# Selecting more than two groups from a big data frame for correlation and plotting multiple lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

Selecting more than two groups from a big data frame for correlation and plotting multiple lines.
I have data made of several groups with time series (i.e.BO,OM1,OM2,OM3,BM1,BM2,BM3 etc.), and I need to calculate correlation for three groups (i.e. OM1, OM2, OM3) and draw a line chart using specific three groups with the baseline (BO).
I'm a beginner of R,I can only draw charts using all the groups, I don't know how to select specific groups to do it. Please help me.

The data frame like this:

| Date | Type | Da |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06/04/2022 | BO | 5.7 |
| 06/04/2022 | OM1 | 8.5 |
| 06/04/2022 | OM2 | 9.4 |
| 06/04/2022 | OM3 | 11 |
| 07/04/2022 | BO | 6.8 |
| 07/04/2022 | OM1 | 9.6 |
| 07/04/2022 | OM2 | 10.4 |
| 07/04/2022 | OM3 | 12.6 |
| 08/04/2022 | BO | 7.7 |
| 08/04/2022 | OM1 | 10.6 |
| 07/04/2022 | OM2 | 12.4 |
| 07/04/2022 | OM3 | 13.5 |

Comment: Could you please share some code you tried and data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: I tried this to plot and the graph shows the two specific types with NA. I can't continue to draw line on it > ggplot(data = data_long) + 
+     geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Emissions, fill=factor(Type, levels = c("BO","OM1"))))

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. We would be happy to help, but you really haven't given us enough information to help you. If you could edit your question to include data (in text form that we can copy/paste) and include your code, I'm sure we can solve your issues. Please do this by editing your question (using the "edit" link under your question) rather than putting code or data in the comments. Thank you.